# I should be able to see new answers while editing

Tags: feature-request, edits, answers, notifications

I answered a question which I (and others) didn't understood correctly. After the question was clarified, I edited my wrong original answer and added the right solution.

Meanwhile, while I was editing, another user answered the question in a new answer with more or less the same content as my answer.

I'm not that experienced, so I didn't look at new answers and overlooked that answer. My post got accepted and gained all the upvotes.

I'm not sure how to behave in this situation: remove the edit, posting the edit as a new answer and deleting my answer, or doing nothing and leaving my post as-is.

In my opinion, the best solution would be that I get informed about new answers. So, why can't I see new answers while editing as I do when posting a new answer? This should be implemented as a feature.

Comment: I've made an edit to rephrase the title and end of this post as a feature request (as indicated by the [feature-request] tag), rather than a support question about why the site doesn't work this way currently.

Answer (score 7):

What happened? One (presumably) correct and valid answer got upvotes and an accept, another correct and valid answer got zilch.

Ideally that shouldn't happen, and it sucks when your answer gets zilch, but it happens all the time.

Upvoting the other answer is pretty much all you can do.

Now here we have the situation that you started out with an incorrect answer due to misunderstanding the question and the other answer was posted while you were editing to correct your answer, and if you had known of the other answer, you might have decided to delete your answer instead of correcting it.

Meh. There are hundreds of answers that say pretty much the same thing as another one posted every day.

Leave the situation as is, feel sorry for the person posting the underappreciated answer and move on.

As for why there's no notification of new answers while editing, I suppose it was considered a rare occasion that an incorrect answer is corrected, and getting notifications while cleaning up formatting or similar would be too much noise.

With the new unobtrusive notifications, however, I think it wouldn't be too disturbing, and it would occasionally be nice to have, so I support your implicit request.